# Class not being called in Symfony after installing it with composer

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I have this directory structure:

```
symfonyproject/src/mybundle/composer.json
```

Inside of this bundle I did a:

```
composer require sabre/xml
```

It got installed fine, just like every other installed packaged, however it won't load.

```
use Sabre;

...

$writer = new Sabre\Xml\Writer();
```

This gives me this error:

> Attempted to load class "Writer" from namespace "Sabre\Xml". Did you
>   forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

I have checked: `symfonyproject/src/mybundle/vendor/composer/autoloade_psr4`

And the parameters are there:

```
'Sabre\\Xml\\' => array($vendorDir . '/sabre/xml/lib'),
'Sabre\\Uri\\' => array($vendorDir . '/sabre/uri/lib'),
```

I am not sure what am I doing wrong here. Other packages work. Any help?

Comment: Did you require `vendor/autoload.php` anywhere in your code? I've tried installing `sabre/xml` package and your snippet is working fine (apart from a warning: `The use statement with non-compound name 'Sabre' has no effect`)

Comment: @EdiModrić It works after I add: include ("/var/www/html/myproject/src/mybundel/vendor/autoload.php"); to my controller however the rest of vendors work just fine without needing to include this... weird.

Comment: Why did you add this dependency in `symfonyproject/src/mybundle` instead of  project root?

Comment: @rob006 This is how the bundle is distributed... I get the bundle instead of the entire project and I cannot change it.

Comment: @prgrm If this is standalone bundle, why you're not installing it by composer as a regular dependency?

Comment: @prgrm You have to add `sabre\xml` to your root `composer.json` and then it will work, or even better, install the bundle itself via Composer. Placing the bundle directly in your `src` folder does not install nor register in autoloader bundle dependencies.

Comment: Ok I will give it a try.